# How to create delete method in SQLite for deleting single item not the whole checklist?

Tags: java, android

I'll post only relevant code.
This is Activity which adds checklist to database.

```
public class AddChecklist extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAddItem;
public LinearLayout linearLayout;
ArrayList<String> itemList;
ArrayList<String> stateList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_checklist);
 

    btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addView();
        }
    });
}

public void addView() {

    View checklistView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.checklist_view, null, false);
    EditText etChecklistItem = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);

    etChecklistItem.requestFocus();
    linearLayout.addView(checklistView);

    ImageView imgDelete = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);

    imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeView(checklistView);
        }
    });
}

public void removeView(View view) {
    linearLayout.removeView(view);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.btn_save:
            ChecklistHelper checklistHelper = new ChecklistHelper();

            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                EditText etChecklistItem = v.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
                CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    checklistHelper.setStatus("1");
                } else
                    checklistHelper.setStatus("0");

                itemList.add(etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
                stateList.add(checklistHelper.getStatus());
            }

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String items : itemList) {
                stringBuilder.append(items);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }

            StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String state : stateList) {
                stringBuilder1.append(state);
                stringBuilder1.append("\n");
            }

            String items = stringBuilder.toString();
            String state = stringBuilder1.toString();

            dbHelper.insertChecklist(state, items, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

This is insert checklist method in SQLiteHelper class.

```
 public boolean insertChecklist(String status, String content, String date, String time, long now){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
    c.put(CHECKLIST_STATUS, status);
    c.put(CHECKLIST_CONTENT, content);
    c.put(CHECKLIST_DATE, date);
    c.put(CHECKLIST_TIME, time);
    c.put(CHECKLIST_NOW, now);

    long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(CHECKLIST_TABLE, null, c);
        Log.d("check", "checklist inserted -> ID = " + id);
        return true;
}
```

This is the delete method for deleting the whole checklist, not for individual items.

```
 public void deleteChecklist(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(CHECKLIST_TABLE, CHECKLIST_ID + " =? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
 }
```

Here I want a method like above, but only for deleting selected item, like this image.. Look at this image.
[look this image](https://pasteboard.co/iZBY5bleB78C.png)

Comment: Your `CHECKLIST_TABLE` appears to be a table of multiple rows of "status/content/date/time/now" columns. The `deleteChecklist` method should delete a single row from the table. What exactly is it you want to do? Change just one of the values in a row in the table? (e.g. change "status" to something else in a given row?) Or is the method to delete a given row not working as expected?

Comment: @TylerV let me explain a bit more. Let's say I insert these values to database ( item a, item b, item c, item d),  these four values go to a single row because I use StringBuilder to do that with a separator ("\n"), because of that all these four items share one (ID). I have no problem adding and showing in RecyclerView. Also deleting a row which include these four items is working, but deleting one item is difficult to create a method for. I have a RecyclerView with two ViewHolders, and one ViewHolder has another RecyclerView in it.

Comment: I suggest you not do that, add one "row" per unique item... Using a database format that is amenable to the operations you want to perform is important. If you don't, you will have to read the whole row, edit it, and re-write it.